# Programmatically show tooltip in winforms application

Tags: winforms

How can I programatically cause a control's tooltip to show in a Winforms app without needing the mouse to hover over the control?  (P/Invoke is ok if necessary).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are using the `Tooltip` control on the form, you can do it like this:

`ToolTip1.Show("Text to display", Control)`

The [MSDN documentation for the ToolTip control's "Show" method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.show.aspx) has all the different variations on this and how to use them.

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. If you do that then the tooltip will show but it will also show everytime you move the mouse over the control there after. Isn't there a way to just show the tooltip on command one time?

Comment: No, using the "Show" command shows the tooltip only that one time. To make the tooltip show any time the mouse is over the control, you'd set the "ToolTipText" property of the control itself.

Comment: Jordan S is right. Show method sets the ToolTip text associated with the specified control.

Comment: Confirming @PICyourBrain's behaviour, though I don't think that this should be the case.

Answer (score 10):

```
System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip ToolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
ToolTip1.SetToolTip(this.textBox1, "Hello");
```

The tooltip will be set over the control "textBox1".

Have a read here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288412.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First You need to add tooltip control to the form
Second attach the tooltip control to some control you want the tooltip to show on (MyControl)
Third do this:
Tooltip1.Show("My ToolTip Text", MyControl)

Answer (score 1):

Kevin, if you want to create your own balloon, read this link:[Task 3: Showing Balloon tips](http://www.microsoft.com/indonesia/msdn/pinvoke.aspx). There mentioned NativeMethods class with the TOOLTIPS_CLASS constant.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use:

```
static HWND hwndToolTip = NULL;

void CreateToolTip( HWND hWndControl, TCHAR *tipText )
{  
    BOOL success;

  if( hwndToolTip == NULL )
  {
    hwndToolTip = CreateWindow(  TOOLTIPS_CLASS, 
                                 NULL, 
                                 WS_POPUP | TTS_NOPREFIX | TTS_ALWAYSTIP,                                     
                                 CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 
                                 CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,                                     
                                 NULL, NULL,
                                 hInstResource, 
                                 NULL ); 
  }

  if( hwndToolTip )
  { 
    TOOLINFO ti; 

    ti.cbSize   = sizeof(ti); 
    ti.uFlags   = TTF_TRANSPARENT | TTF_SUBCLASS; 
    ti.hwnd     = hWndControl; 
    ti.uId      = 0; 
    ti.hinst    = NULL; 
    ti.lpszText = tipText; 

    GetClientRect( hWndControl, &ti.rect ); 

    success = SendMessage( hwndToolTip, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM) &ti ); 
  }
}
```

Call CreateToolTip function to create a tool tip for a certain control.

Comment: How to  get reference to TOOLTIPS_CLASS, I get a compiler error for HWND, TCHAR and many more. These don't seem to be defined in .Net. Do I have to add a reference?

Answer (score 0):

If you create your variable private to the whole form, you will be able to call the sub for the and adjust the initialdelay.

```
Public Class MyForm        
Private MyTooltip As New ToolTip        
...        
Sub ApplyToolTips        
'For default        
ApplyToolTips (1000)        
End Sub        

Sub ApplyTooltips (ByVal Delay as Integer)        

MyTooltip .InitialDelay = Delay        
MyTooltip.AutoPopDelay = 5000        
...        
MyTooltip.SetToolTip(Me.btnClose, "Close the form")        

End Sub       

Private Sub Btn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn.Click           
    Dim PicBox As PictureBox = CType(sender, PictureBox)        
    ApplyTooltips (0)       
    ApplyTooltips (1000)       
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying @Keithius's code and finding that the tip showed with mouse-over once the `OnClick` code had run, I ended up doing this:

Button `Click` event:

```
ToolTip1.Show("Text to display", Control);
```

Button `MouseLeave` event:

```
ToolTip1.Hide(Control);
```

But then I found that if I specified a position - using either explicit `x` and `y` co-ords or a `Point`, it worked as expected:

Button `Click` event:

```
ToolTip1.Show("Text to display", Control, Control.Width+20, 0, 2000);
```

or

```
ToolTip1.Show("Text to display", Control, new Point(Control.Width+20, 0), 2000);
```

This is possibly due to the modality of some overloads as mentioned in the [Microsoft doco](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip.show).