# Tooltip Refresh

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I have a button which has a tooltip when you click the button the tooltip changes. my problem is, if you are hovering over the button and the tool tip shows up then click the button. the tool tip dose not change until you re-hover.

is there a way to refresh the tool-tip?

Comment: How are you showing the tooltip?

Comment: when you hove over it. its a built in property within the button class. tooltipText

Comment: can you show us the code?

Comment: button.ToolTipText = "text here ";

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programatically show tooltip in winforms application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63439/programatically-show-tooltip-in-winforms-application)

Comment: You will have to add a ToolTip to the Form, then on text changed do ToolTip.Show("TT Text", Button1);

Comment: Adding to Adrew's comment: You can also use         `toolTip1.SetToolTip(button1, "text");` to reset the tooltip text, e.g. on MouseLeave or whenever.. Note the reversed parameters! Also note: there is __no built-in__ property `ToolTipText` in the Button class. Look at the designer file and you'll see that it also calls: `this.toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.button1, "text");`

Answer (score 0):

Just invoke the toolTip visibility = hidden from the on-click function of your button.