# How can I display information from database onto a tooltip for a picturebox?

Tags: c#

Does anyone know how to take information from a database and display onto a picture box via a tooltip?

Comment: [How to retrieve data from SQL Server](https://www.comeausoftware.com/2018/03/retrieve-data-sql-server-csharp/) [Display Tooltip programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63439/programmatically-show-tooltip-in-winforms-application)

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the database with access or mysql, but I don't think the received data can be shown in the picture box.